# File permissions with no sense (Linux, Apache)

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a problem with file permissions which is driving me crazy. I have a Perl web app which installs itself, copying some files, creating DB, and so on. All works fine, except for some image files. These images aren't accesible by Apache:

```
(13) Permission denied: access to /path/to/image.gif denied
```

But, the file es 644. I've tried chmod 777, and chown to Apache user, without positive results.

And what drives me crazy: if I copy the file, then rename old file and rename new file, it works!

```
mv image.gif image.gif.bak
cp image.gif.bak image.gif
```

Files are identical, same size, same permissions, same owner and group. I can see both in a imageviewer. But, if I restore original file (remove the "new" file and rename the "old" file to its original name) I got a "permission denied" again:

```
rm image.gif
mv image.gif.bak image.gif
```

This issue occurs with all image files, but not with text files (static html, css...).

What could be causing this strange behavior?

I'm using Apache 2.2.3 under CentOs 5.5. Perl scripts (Perl 5.8.8) runs with Suexec.

Comment: Is selinux enabled?

Comment: Yes embobo, that was the problem: a little mess with SELinux contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that perhaps SELinux is causing problems?  Disable it and see things start working:

```
su -
/sbin/setenforce 0
```

If things worked after disabling it, try `restorecon` and re-enable SELinux to see if maybe your SELinux contexts were screwed up.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! I'm not familiarize with SELinux nor CentOS (usually use Debian/Ubuntu Server) so I didn't think about it. In addition, the install script has messed up with file contexts, some of them didn't get repaired with restorecon, but can repair them with chcon. I'm going to read more about SELinux.Thanks JeffG!

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you have a permission problem due to

- Using `suexec`, meaning that the CGI script and Apache do/may not run under the same user/group
- I don't see in your description that you checked the path up to the image file, not only the file itself

`suexec` will have the script executed under the owner user and groups of the script. Apache itself will keep loading files using its own user/group as defined in httpd.conf (or apache[2].conf, conf.d/...).

- Perform a `ls -d` of the path directories up to the images files, to ensure Apache has at least a `--x` access (no view, but access to named file).
- You can give access a directory to Apache by changing the group to the Apache group (search `Group` in the configuration files) with `chgrp apache-group directory`, and adding the `x` access to that same directory `chmod g+x directory`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write about it. Apache is member of the user who runs suexec, permissions are OK and the path is OK. The problem was in SELinux. Thank you ring0!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mime types in apache setup for the image files? Can you do the command ls -l in the directory your looking at and paste the output here.